# how do you provide custom error messages for another locale? (action mailer)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, internationalization, actionmailer

**working:** [works when locale is `en`] When I click the 'send' button it displays error messages saying `name is blank`, `email is blank`, etc (when the fields are empty) which is fine. the output is listed below:

```
3 errors prohibited this message from being sent:

Email can't be blank
Email is invalid
Subject can't be blank
```

**not working:** however [not working when locale is `es`] when I click the 'send' button it displays error messages which is listed below:

```
3 errors prohibited this message from being sent:

Email translation missing: es.activemodel.errors.models.message.attributes.email.blank
Email translation missing: es.activemodel.errors.models.message.attributes.email.invalid
Subject translation missing: es.activemodel.errors.models.message.attributes.subject.blank
```

**Question** so how do I make this translation work help needed please, running out of time.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have the values `es.activemodel.errors.models.message.attributes.email.blank
` set in your es locale file?

Comment: actually I do not. let me add that!

Comment: you solved my problem, post an answer I will up-vote and accept your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have the values es.activemodel.errors.models.message.attributes.email.blank set in your es locale file?

Like this in the `es.yml` :

```
es:
  activemodel:
    errors:
      models:
        message:
          attributes:
            email:
              blank: "I don't speak spanish I can't give an example ... Shame on me!"
```

Comment: not bad actually but tired of doing this back-end services for this gigantic web application.

Comment: I advise you to take a look at this guide: https://github.com/bbatsov/rails-style-guide It gives you the guidelines and hints for usefull gems ;)